# Android sms broadcast receiver - emoji

Tags: android, sms

I'm writing a small android app which has a broadcast receiver for incoming sms messages. Normal text works just fine, but emoji show up as weird characters ().

The relevant code:

```
class SmsReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

   override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
     val pdus = intent.extras?.get("pdus") as Array<ByteArray>

     pdus.map { SmsMessage.createFromPdu(it) }
        .forEach { Log.i("Receiver", "Got message ${it.displayMessageBody}") }
   }
```

The message I'm sending to the emulator:

What I get in my log file: 
`I/Receiver: Got message `

Does anyone know how to get the proper message text?

---

**UPDATE**

So after going down a rabbit hole of encodings and the EmojiCompat library, I discovered it's an issue with the emulator itself. When I got hold of a second phone and tried it on an actual device, it just worked. I created a bug with the android developers so hopefully they have a fix: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149141727

Comment: might be helpful: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat

Answer (score 0):

The message you are sending the emulator is ascii, and the message you are displaying to the log is UTF8, you need to read it as ascii

Comment: Hi Lena, thanks for the input. It appears to be an issue with the emulator itself, see my update to the question